# Regex to update date precision

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that contains the following date range format variations. I need to find and replace with hour precision using a single java regex pattern. The date range is variable. Can you come up with a regex for me?

**String Example**

published_date:{05/31/16.23:41:24-?}

published_date:{05/31/16.23:41:24-06/21/16.23:41:24}

**Expected Results**

published_date:{05/31/16.23:00:00-?}

published_date:{05/31/16.23:00:00-06/21/16.23:00:00}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This regex will find substrings that look like date/time stamps like `05/31/16.23:41:24`. It'll capture the date and hour portions of and allow you to replace the minutes and seconds with `00`.

```regex
([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

**Replace With:** `$1:00:00`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/qK8bL7/1

**Sample text**

```
published_date:{05/31/16.23:41:24-?}

published_date:{05/31/16.23:41:24-06/21/16.23:41:24}
```

**After Replacement**

```
published_date:{05/31/16.23:00:00-?}

published_date:{05/31/16.23:00:00-06/21/16.23:00:00}
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+".

public class Regex {

```
public static void main(String ar[]){
    String st = "05/31/16.23:41:24-06/21/16.23:41:24";

    st = st.replaceAll(":[0-9]+:[0-9]+", ":00:00");
    System.out.println(st);

    st = "05/31/16.23:41:24-?";

    st = st.replaceAll(":[0-9]+:[0-9]+", ":00:00");
    System.out.println(st);

}
```

}